# Linux command for IPV6 IP address compare

Tags: linux, command, ip-address, ipv6

I am trying to get IPV6 IP address on Linux system. I am using below command

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet6 addr" | awk '{print $3}'
```

Please suggest if any improvements needed.
I also want to check if IPV6 IP address is not equal to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

How can that be done ?

Thanks.
Dnyanesh.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 addresses can be represented in several ways; abbreviated (compressed) according to several rules. I would suggest to use the command line `ipv6calc` tool to let it interpret the address and use that output. For example:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet6 addr" | awk '{print $3}' | \
   ipv6calc --addr_to_fulluncompressed
fe80:0000:0000:0000:dead:beaf:dead:beef/64
```

I find this this `--addr_to_fulluncompressed` option very useful to compare addresses quite reliably.

On the other hand, you could check the IPv6 address type directly using `--out ipv6addrtype` and grep for `loopback`, but on my installation it doesn't seen to work for some reason.

Comment: It's `ipv6addr`not `ipv6addrtype ` isn't it?

Comment: @alk No, see output of `ipv6calc --out -h`. If the address type is `loopback`, then it's equal to `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`, right?

Comment: Ahok, I see `ipv6addr`  wouldn't make sense, sry. Anyhow, if I pass `--out ipv6addrtype` it's printing `Outputtype isn't implemented` ...

Comment: @alk Yeah, indeed. Weird, huh?

Comment: @alk `--showinfo` makes it to show all information, regardless of the output requested in `--out`.

Comment: @alk It does show the IPv6 address type when using `--showinfo`, yet together with all other (default) output. So, the output type *is* implemented, however, selecting it as the sole output isn't apparently. Seems like a bug.